# How to shrink table cell to fit content height?

Tags: html, css

I've already tried some of the solutions provided by this site but apparently, none of them worked for me. So I thought I'd post this as another question.

I have this table containing buttons which I've designed using CSS.[image]

I did not set the table height and width so it should adjust itself according to its content. The problem is there's this 'gap' below the buttons, as seen from the image and I can't seem to find a way to remove this. I've also tried setting every cell height but it didn't work.

I have this for the button

```
.arrow
{
background-color:#78E9DE;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px 0px #45C3B8;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
border: none;
font-size: 30px;
};
```

and a simple html table

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>[up button here]</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>[left button here]</td>
  <td></td>
  <td>[right button here]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td></td>
  <td>[down button here]</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want fit every cell with the content inside so it would look nice and easier to click. Please help thanks.

Comment: Try setting `table > tr, table > tr > td { line-height:1;}`

Comment: I tried it but nothing happens :(

Comment: Have you tried using `height: 100%`  ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table,td {
  padding: 0;
}
img {
  display: inherit;
}
```

and here is the result :

Comment: I tried but it shrinks only by at least a pixel. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: can I have images of buttons you used to give it another shot?

Comment: I did not use images for the buttons. I used CSS.